# Vertically aligning Images with text to the bottom

Tags: html, css

Markup:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="selected">
        <img src="Images/thumb1selected.png" />
        <p><a>Image 1</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="Images/thumb2.png" />
        <p><a>Image 2</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="Images/thumb3.png" />
        <p><a>Image 3</a></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation li
{
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:relative;
    height: 140px; 
    width: 120px; 
}
.navigation li>img
{
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
}
.navigation li>p
{
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

And this is the result.

[image]

The images are correctly bottom aligned. But I want the text to come below the image instead of above the image. How shall I change the CSS to achieve this?

Comment: The `img` has the property `position:absolute; bottom:0` - that will put the images to the bottom of their container, meaning nothing (including your text) will go below them.

Comment: i tried something like bottom 20 to no avail..

Comment: Right, because when using `position:absolute`, you effectively take that element out of the 'flow' of the page. I would suggest not using `position:absolute` - you can accomplish this easily without having to using positioning at all.

Comment: see the fiddle here; it demonstrates how you don't need to use positioning to accomplish this, as well as removes the `<p>` from the `<li>` (not allowed). http://jsfiddle.net/fRhqH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the html you could do this:

```
.navigation 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation li
{
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:relative;
    height: 140px; 
    width: 120px; 
}
.navigation li>img
{
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 30px;
}
.navigation li>p
{
    padding-left: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

This won't re-size well if the text is long though.

If you can/are willing to change the html, I would lay it out more like this:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="selected">
        <div class="imageContainer">
            <img src="Images/thumb1selected.png" />
        </div>
        <p><a>Image 1</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="imageContainer">
             <img src="Images/thumb2.png" />
        </div>
        <p><a>Image 2</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="imageContainer">
            <img src="Images/thumb3.png" />
        </div>
        <p><a>Image 3</a></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With CSS along the lines of:

```
.navigation 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation li
{
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 120px;
}
.navigation .imageContainer
{
    height: 140px; 
    width: 120px;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}
.navigation li>img
{
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
}
.navigation li>p
{
    padding-left: 25px;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: +1: this solution works. i tried till bottom:20. any ideas why didn't that work?

Comment: Did you try that with the p having absolute positioning as well?

Comment: If not, then it's because absolutely positioned elements (the images) are removed from the normal flow so the p is the first thing that is in the flow inside the li and as such is presented at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS style to :

```
.navigation li>img
{
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    top:0;
}
.navigation li>p
{
    padding-left: 25px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/rctjS/.

This won't works with `bottom:20`  beacause you have to set the bottom edge position in px, cm, etc. Negative values are allowed. e.g. : `bottom:20px`